# Can I simulate an empty lambda with C++03 standard library features?

Tags: c++, c++03

I'm stuck on GCC 4.4, so despite introducing `-std=c++0x` to my codebase have no use of lambdas.

Is there a C++03 equivalent to an empty lambda `[](){}`, that I could use safely as a default argument for a generic argument with some type `Callback`?

I ask because the old `std::plus`, `std::less` etc were handy but I can't seem to find a no-op, `void`-returning equivalent.

Comment: I would try to get unstuck from GCC 4.4; I am sure you would be able to compile GCC 6 from source code.

Comment: What's actually wrong with rolling your own?

Comment: If you want an STL function what about a nonsensical `std::swap`?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Sometimes you can't because of various restrictions/requirements.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I don't want to complicate our build environment from what CentOS 6's package manager gives us. If I can help it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Nothing (and, for now, that's what I'm doing) but using something that already exists in the stdlib would be better.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I know that, but then it becomes a management or organizational question, so out of scope on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
struct noop {
  static void do_nothing(){};
  void operator()()const{};
  typedef void(*pf)();
  operator pf()const { return do_nothing; }
};
```

`noop()` is pretty equivalent to `[](){}`.

It even converts to function pointer like the noop lambda does.

Comment: I'm doing that; admittedly my question wasn't clear but I was hoping for something in the stdlib to avoid having to define this.

Comment: Although when I say "that", not quite "that"; mine's just a bloody function pointer. This is much better thanks to inlining yay

Comment: @light I mean we could bind1st 0 to less twice, but why?  It would be about as many characters, fail to have the convert-to-function ptr feature, and would require more work by the optimizer to eliminate.

Comment: I guess I was wondering whether the stdlib packaged exactly what you have here. :P